# Integrating Stripe Payments in iOS

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe payments into my iOS app and I can't seem to solve these errors. I'm not sure if they have anything to do with my bridging header but if anyone could take a look at the code.
Many thanks in advance.
This is the code in my ViewControllerClass:

```
class PaymentInfoViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    **var stripeView: STPView = STPView()**

    @IBOutlet var cardNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var expiryDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var cvc: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var sendPaymentInfo: UIButton!
    @IBAction func getStripeToken(sender: AnyObject) {
        let creditCard = STPCard() //creating a stripe card object
        creditCard.number = cardNumber.text
        creditCard.cvc = cvc.text

        //extracting month and year values from expiry date
        if (!expiryDate.text.isEmpty){
            let expArr = expiryDate.text.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
            if (expArr.count > 1)
            {
                var expMonth: NSNumber = expArr[0].toInt()!
                var expYear: NSNumber = expArr[1].toInt()!

                creditCard.expMonth = expMonth.unsignedLongValue
                creditCard.expYear = expYear.unsignedLongValue
            }
        }

        var error: NSError?
        if (creditCard.validateCardReturningError(&error)){
            var stripeError: NSError!
            **Stripe.createTokenWithCard(creditCard, completion: { (token, stripeError) -> Void in**
                if (stripeError != nil){
                    println("there is error");
                }
                else{
                    self.cardNumber.text = ""
                    self.expiryDate.text = ""
                    self.cvc.text = ""


                    //shows your stripe token
                    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Your stripe token is: " + token.tokenId, message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    var defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
        }else{
            //shows alert if information is not correct
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please enter valid credit card details", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            var defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }


    }
```

Sections enclosed with double asterisks are where the compile errors are.

Code from bridging header:

```
#import "Stripe.h"
@import Foundation;
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: First error: Use of undeclared type "STPView"

Comment: Second Error: 'createTokenWithCard( :completion:)' is unavailable

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an SDK version above 3.0, you should take a look at the migrations guides on github: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios#migration-guides.

Specifically- "Before version 3.0, most token-creation methods were class methods on the Stripe class. These are now all instance methods on the STPAPIClient class."

You may want have better luck with something like this (starting from your getStripeToken function):
```@IBAction func getStripeToken(sender: AnyObject){
        let creditCard = STPCard()
        let StripePublicKey = "your_key_here"
        let stpClient = STPAPIClient(publishableKey: StripePublicKey)

````
    creditCard.number = cardNum.text
    creditCard.cvc = cvc.text

    if (!exp.text.isEmpty) {
        let expArr = exp.text.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
        if (expArr.count > 1) {
            var expMonth: NSNumber = expArr[0].toInt()!
            var expYear: NSNumber = expArr[1].toInt()!

            creditCard.expMonth = expMonth.unsignedLongValue
            creditCard.expYear = expYear.unsignedLongValue
        }
    }

    var error: NSError?
    if (creditCard.validateCardReturningError(&error)){
        var stripeError: NSError!
        stpClient.createTokenWithCard(creditCard, completion: { (token, stripeError) -> Void in
            if (stripeError != nil){
                println("there is error");
            }
            else{
                self.cardNum.text = ""
                self.exp.text = ""
                self.cvc.text = ""
                self.email.text = ""

                var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Your stripe token is: " + token!.tokenId, message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                var defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }```
````